# What is different among hlint, hdevtools and ghc-mod

Tags: haskell

I am looking for code lint, type query, auto type-insert and misc helper to use with vim (like autocomplete).

After some research I found multiple similar tools that migth do what I want

- hlint
- hdevtools
- ghc-mod

**The main question,** Are these all basically the same tool?

When I do some testing I found that only ghc-mod is working out-of-the-box (for code lint, havn't try any Type-helper function)

```
$ cat test.hs 
main = putStrLn "test"
$ ghc-mod check test.hs 
test.hs:1:1:Warning: Top-level binding with no type signature: main :: IO ()
$ hdevtools check test.hs 
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
$ hlint test.hs 
No hints
```

Do I need to make any configuration file for hlint and hdevtools?

```
$ hdevtools --version
hdevtools: version 0.1.4.1 (ghc-8.0.1-x86_64-linux, cabal-1.24.0.0)
$ hlint --version
HLint v1.9.35, (C) Neil Mitchell 2006-2016
$ ghc-mod --version
ghc-mod version 5.6.0.0 compiled by GHC 8.0.1
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.1
```

All tools was installed by `stack install` and I have `/home/wizzup/.local/bin` in `$PATH`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`ghc-mod` installs a binary named `ghc-mod` to your `$PATH` which is able to load and interrogate your package database and source code (there is also an "interactive" version called `ghc-modi` that reads in commands from standard in and sticks around). It uses the GHC and Cabal APIs to do so. Progress stalled for a while but has now returned to a bustling state. There are Emacs/Vim/Sublime packages that know how to talk to `ghc-mod` and provide various IDE-like features for end-users: typechecking, holes, program/proof search, find-definition.

`hdevtools` is a newer project, inspired by `ghc-mod`. It is architecturally similar – running a persistent background server with per-editor packages.  It is designed to completely replace `ghc-mod`. The differences between `ghc-mod` and `hdevtools` seem to be philosophical. `hdevtools` has fewer of the fancy ghc-mod features but is (in my experience) substantially faster. Something that struck out from a cursory glance at the code bases: `hdevtools` seems to rely on the GHC API to implement a GHCi-like server, capable of quickly reloading code. Perhaps that was the key decision to getting good performance? I am sure I am grossly oversimplifying.

`hlint` is very different. It is an old old project (started in 2006 by Neil Mitchell, one of the Haskell community elders). It is able to detect typical bad Haskell habits (e.g. using `concat . map` instead of `concatMap`) and, in some cases, lightly refactor them away. It relies on the `haskell-src-exts` which parses Haskell code into ASTs. I believe `hlint` does not even require a full type-check of the code base: it can look at the abstract syntax tree alone to suggest changes and sound alerts. You would typically choose either `ghc-mod` or `hdevtools` and use them in *conjunction* with `hlint` to get the full Haskell IDE experience.

We should take the time here to also mention FP Complete's `intero` project, which runs ghci and is similar to `hdevtools`. It only works if your editor is Emacs and you are using stack, however. I was unable to find good documentation on how it differs from `ghc-mod` or `hdevtools`; one presumes it was intended to give Emacs users a better experience, as you can often get into the situation where `hdevtools`/`ghc-mod` will stubbornly refuse to run because of a compiler or an editor package mismatch. With `intero` you can get up and running with a small snippet of Elisp.

It's a big old mess!